# How to parse:HERA was passed into law in 2008 and it governs FHFA

Tags: meaning

> HERA was passed into law in 2008 and it governs FHFA

source:http://seekingalpha.com/article/4028577-mechanics-decoupling-gses-net-worth-sweep

HERA : the sister and consort of Zeus  in the dictionary.
it governs FHFA, the word *it* means HERA?

What does the sentence mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this context, HERA doesn't mean the sister of Zeus, but rather refers to the [Housing and Economic Recovery Act](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Housing_and_Economic_Recovery_Act_of_2008).

HERA is used as an acronym here, and not as a person's name. You can guess this from the fact that HERA is written in uppercase, and not as Hera.

Further, FHFA refers to [Federal Housing Finance Agency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Federal_Housing_Finance_Agency). This context serves as a further hint to "verify" our interpretation of HERA.

Now it should be clear what your sentence means:

> The Housing and Economic Recovery Act was passed in the year 2008. This Act governs the Federal Housing Finance Agency.